# Put node add form in module

Tags: module, drupal-7

I want to include a node add form within a module page, but I'm not sure exactly how to make Drupal happy - if i do something like

```
global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');    
$form = drupal_get_form("project_node_form", $node_form);
$rtn .= drupal_render($form);
```

I get the error `Call to undefined function user_access()`

Should I wrap it in a function? how to call it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to embed it into the hook: [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) ?